# Boolean test case failing when it should pass

Tags: java, boolean

I am refreshing myself with some Java practice problems to help teach some friends of mine how to code and, embarrassingly enough, I am failing a single test case on a seemingly easy test case and can't see what I am doing wrong. The practice question is:

Given 2 int values, return true if one is negative and one is positive. Except if the parameter `negative` is true, then return true only if both are negative.

My code is:

```
public boolean posNeg(int a, int b, boolean negative) {
  if(negative == true && (a < 0 && b < 0))
    return true;
  else if(negative == false && (a < 0 && b > 0) || (a > 0 && b < 0))
    return true;

  return false;
}
```

And the test case is: `posNeg(1, -1, true)` -> false (My output is true which is incorrect.)

Comment: Instead of negative == true you should code just negative.

Comment: You can write all this with one comparison (see my answer).  In C, even less ;)

Comment: Thanks for all the responses guys! It was really helpful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A shorter version is

```
public boolean posNeg(int a, int b, boolean negative) {
    return (negative ? a & b : a ^ b) < 0;
}
```

This works because `a & b` is negative iff both are negative and `a ^ b` is negative iff one, and only one is negative.

If you used `int` with 0 = false and 1 = true instead of boolean as C (and byte code) does you could write

```
public int posNeg(int a, int b, int neg) {
    return (neg * (a & b) + (1 - neg) * (a ^ b)) >>> -1;
}
```

One trick here is that `>>> -1` gives you the top bit as 0 or 1 for both `int` and `long`.

Comment: you are smarter than jit, +1

Comment: Unless there is something extremely performance-critical about this operation, I think it's better to write readable code, i.e. using normal comparison operations rather than bit operations.

Answer (score 2):

Your output is ok, you should change

```
if( negative == false && (a < 0 && b > 0) || (a > 0 && b < 0))
```

to

```
if(  !negative &&  ( (a < 0 && b > 0)  || (a > 0 && b < 0) ) ) 
                   ^                                       ^
```

`&&` works like multiplication

If you have this

```
negative == false && (a < 0 && b > 0) || (a > 0 && b < 0)
```

is like

```
 ( negative == false && (a < 0 && b > 0) )  || (a > 0 && b < 0)
 ^                                       ^
```

Answer (score 2):

Try simplifying it like this.

```
public boolean posNeg(int a, int b, boolean negative) {
  if (negative) return a < 0 && b < 0;
  else return 1L * a * b < 0L;
}
```

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux Come on ;) No, I don't steal code. I wrote mine than saw the other answers and found the mistake in yours. Will upvote your answer if you like so, NP.

Comment: Well, here you go: +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

This is the culprit:

```
else if(negative == false && (a < 0 && b > 0) || (a > 0 && b < 0))
```

That breaks down into:

```
else if(
    negative == false && (a < 0 && b > 0)
    ||
    (a > 0 && b < 0)
)
```

E.g., it doesn't care about the value of `negative` if the condition after the `||` is true, it follows the path and returns `true`.

You probably want parens in there somewhere. I haven't fully worked through your logic, but possibly you meant:

```
else if(
    negative == false && (
        (a < 0 && b > 0)
        ||
        (a > 0 && b < 0)
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public boolean posNeg(int a, int b, boolean negative)
{
  if(negative)
  {
      return a < 0 && b < 0;
  } else
  {
      return (long) a * b < 0;
  }
}
```

This is translated what you said. Note the smart way of checking if only one is negative:

- `- * -` = `+`
- `- * +` = `-`
- `+ * -` = `-`
- `+ * +` = `+`

But as *@peter.petrov* pointed out: this might overflow if your integers are too big. That is why the cast to the long is required. So a better nice way to check this is to do:

```
(a < 0) ^ (b < 0)
```

Which makes a nice one-liner, using the ternary conditional operator:

```
public static boolean posNeg(int a, int b, boolean negative)
{
    return negative ? a < 0 && b < 0 : ((a < 0) ^ (b < 0));
}
```

Comment: Or simply : `return negative ? a*b > 0 : a*b < 0;`

Comment: This will overflow in many cases: "return a * b < 0". Make sure you go to long.

Comment: @user2336315 Considering he is trying to teach someone basic coding, your example is _far_ to advanced.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to lie in the row:

```
else if(negative == false && (a < 0 && b > 0) || (a > 0 && b < 0))
```

you're writing (false AND false OR true), so the OR case is evaluated to true, thus entering the if-statement.
try writing it like this instead:

```
else if (!negative && ((a < 0 && b > 0 ) || (a > 0 && b < 0)))
```

that is: (false AND (false OR true)), evaluating the negative flag each time

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way too :

```
public boolean posNeg(int a, int b, boolean negative) {
    int a1 = Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(a);
    int b1 = Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(b);
    return negative ? (a1 + b1) == 0 : ((a1 & b1) == 0 && (a1 != b1));
}
```

Explanation :

- If negative is `true`, you want to return true if both numbers are negative so it implies that the left most bit of both number are a 1, so `numberOfLeadingZeros` will return 0 for both.
- If negative is `false`, then if `(a1 & b1 == 0)`, that means that one of the numbers is negative, but it can also means that **both** are negative, so you have to check that `a1 != b1`.